# Python 3 AppIndicator3: What is the dependency?

Tags: indicator, deb, python3

I'm packaging an [app I wrote](https://github.com/mssever/sleep-inhibit) in Python 3 which uses:

```
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3
```

As I'm listing the dependencies, I have been unable to determine what package contains `AppIndicator3`. I guessed `python-appindicator`, but looking at that package it appears that it's for Python 2, not Python 3.

Which package should I depend on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're importing from `gi.repository`. The file for this module is:

```
$ python3 -c 'import gi.repository, sys; print (sys.modules["gi.repository"].__file__)'
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/repository/__init__.py
```

And that file comes from:

```
$ dpkg -S $(python3 -c 'import gi.repository, sys; print (sys.modules["gi.repository"].__file__)')
python3-gi: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/repository/__init__.py
```

So, the package you need (at least on 14.04) is [`python3-gi`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python3-gi).

Answer (score 3):

I followed the procedure described in [muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/772079/464610) on Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME desktop, and got precisely the same output as muru reports for Ubuntu 14.04:

```
python3-gi: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/repository/__init__.py
```

However, in order to run a script containing the line

```
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3
```

I had to install not only `python3-gi` but also `libappindicator3-dev`:

```
sudo apt install libappindicator3-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

For my own indicators, I use  `gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1` as dependency. If I recall correctly `libappindicator3-dev` is for development.  Either one works in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

just open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+T and type

`sudo apt-get install gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1`

No need to install full development package.
Tested on ubuntu 20.04.

*How I arrived at this?*

I tried `sudo apt install libappindicator3-dev` and pressed 'n' (not to install). From the package list the first was `gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1` so installed just that.